# Where "layer_styles" table is listed in the schema tree

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qml, pgadmin-4, style-manager

Where can I find the "layer_style" table in the schema tree?

I am using pgAdmin4, I have connected to the PostgreSQL database using QGIS and added the layer(s) that I want to style.
Then Opened the Style Manager by clicking on the "Style" button in the Layer Styling panel, or by going to the "Layer" menu and selecting "Styles" > "Manage Styles" and in the Style Manager, selected "PostgreSQL" as the storage option.

Now, I am trying to see the saved style file in pgAdmin4, but I could not able to see that.
however, while writing a query

```sql
SELECT * FROM layer_styles
```

it showed that file see the attached file.

How am I supposed to see the [image]"layer_styles" table listed in the schema tree?